# how to open ms-settings:notifications pointing to my application's page?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, notifications

this page https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#system explains how to use the the ms-settings URIs to open specific pages of the windows settings application.

I can currently open the Notifications & actions page using the URI `ms-settings:notifications`

What I want to achieve is to open the notifications page of an application that I've installed on the computer.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: This doesn't exist.

Comment: @harrymc I've looked for it too and couldn't find it

Comment: @harrymc post it as an answer so I can accept it if I get no other feedback =)

Answer (score 0):

Negative answer : This is impossible when using `ms-settings:notifications`,
meaning that Windows cannot be that specific.